# PHP-CRUD-API inserting NULL on columns

Tags: php, api

I'm using ([PHP-CRUD-API](https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api)) with a MySQL database.

When I sent a simple POST passing in the body a JSON object, VARCHAR(255) columns of the table receive NULL values.

This is my CREATE TABLE statement

```
CREATE TABLE users (   id integer NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  name varchar(255) ,  email varchar(255),  PRIMARY KEY (id)  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

When I send a POST passing in the body

```
{"id": 1, "name": "Someone", "email": "something@x.com"}
```

it returns status 200, the row is inserted in the table, but NAME and EMAIL columns has NULL values.

When I send a GET everything is correct (I've inserted manually some rows to test this).

What am I missing?

**EDITED:** If I sent the data as x-www-form-urlencoded on the request, it works. I prefer to pass a JSON object in the body, but...

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Can you clarify the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is the default behavior of your MySQL setup on inserting with missing values. If you want empty strings, you should add "NOT NULL" before the "varchar" type definition.

NB: I'm the author of PHP-CRUD-API

Comment: I'm passing non null values on my json object. If I put the NOT NULL constraint on the columns, the insert fails. If I keep the table with the above definition, even the not null (and not missing either) values passed on my json object are stored as null in the table. I supposed that my json would be used to populate the columns. Nothing else...